# Excel VBA not running when data is entered directly in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to understand why the vba code is not running when the user enters something directly on the cell. Basically, I had enabled the Data Validation and I'm provinding the user with a set of data it can choose. If the user just enters the "status" on the cell, the macro is not being triggered. Do you know how to fix this problem?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("E:E"), Target)


'Doing
xOffsetColumn = 4
If ActiveCell.Value = "Doing" Then
 If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
         If Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = "" Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss"
         End If
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
End If
```

Comment: Is this to check for entering `Doing` in column `E`?  Your macro only runs when `ActiveCell.Value = "Doing"`  You should really use `Target` here.  Also, this `If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then` should be the first logical check I suppose.

Comment: Make sure that Application Enable Events  before you import value is equal to TRUE using immediate window.

Comment: How do you know your macro is not triggered? Maybe you can add a `Msgbox "macro startted"` to see when it's triggered. All your actions are wrapped in `If ActiveCell.Value = "Doing" Then`, so if value of activecell is not "doing" then nothing will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options for an answer.

**Option 1:** Someone (probably you) somehow has disabled the events. Thus run this small vba code to enable them back:

```
Sub EnableBack
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Option 2:**
You are actually entering "Doing" and expecting something to happen. This is not what the code is doing. This line:

`If ActiveCell.Value = "Doing" Then`

actually checks the cell below the Target one. To make sure that the correct cell is with Doing change that line to:

`If Target.Value = "Doing" Then`

As a best practice, consider `If UCase(Target.Value) = "DOING" Then`, thus you would catch the cases with "Doing", "doing", "DOING" and etc.

Comment: It is certainly Option 2